# Multi-stage YAML Azure Pipeline conditional stage visibility

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

We're starting down the path to move our Azure Pipelines from Classic to YAML. Is it possible with multi-stage pipelines to have stages not show up in the stages list, based on conditional logic?

For example, we have multi-stage pipelines that build and then are deployed to one or more environments via pipeline stages. When the build occurs, say, on non-trunk branches, we don't want certain environments to be available at all for deployment. We have that logic working, but the excluded environment stages still show up, for example, in the pipeline run history.

Can we make these stages not show up at all based on conditional logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround , you can use [Conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion). For example:

```
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
  - stage: prod
    dependsOn: staging
    jobs:
    - job: deploy_prod
      pool:
        vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
      steps:
      - script: echo Prod
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! It doesn't feel like a workaround. It feels like a solution! Hopefully I can test it out this week. 

Comment: @Hugh i have applied your code but showing: The pipeline must contain at least one stage with no dependencies.